# Is there a "what links here" feature for GitHub?

Tags: github

I know its issue management system has something similar implemented. From another issue, if we link to another issue (on GitHub of course) the latter will show the source from where it was linked:

[image: GitHub link example]

However, a better example of a web site that implements that feature really well would be Wikipedia:

[image: Wikipedia example]

The reason I am looking for this: I am interested in learning about other GitHub projects that are based off a project. For e.g.

[`ng-annotate`](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) is a npm project (hosted on GitHub). [`grunt-ng-annotate`](https://github.com/mzgol/grunt-ng-annotate) is, I believe, based on it. However, in the latter project there is a link saying ng-annotate, but it links to the npm page, which links to the first project I've mentioned.

I am interested in learning of any other projects that are based off ng-annotate.

Comment: You just want to know what branches there are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling "find related github projects", I find this service: [gazer](http://www.yasiv.com/github).

It seems working perfectly.

In your case, [ng-annotate related github projects](http://www.yasiv.com/github/#/costars?q=olov%2Fng-annotate) yield many results.